# Disable phpMyAdmin root access

Tags: phpmyadmin, root

I want to disable the root user login in my phpmyadmin version  4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2, I wrote this config.inc.php:

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = false;
```

But I can connect with root. Why?

Comment: Do you have more than one server defined?

Comment: No, I have the default phpmyadmin installation on ubuntu server. The confi.inc.php is a copy of the default sample with just the AllowRoot added

Comment: Maybe open an issue: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues  but you are running an old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved thi issue upgrading phpMyAdmin, it was a bug.